# Does the OpenZeppelin nonReentrant modifier block calling all functions that have the modifier on them, or it keeps a separate state for each function

Tags: openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts, reentrant-attacks, modifiers

Would the [**nonReentrant**](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/security#ReentrancyGuard-nonReentrant--) modifier from the OpenZeppelin ReentrancyGuard library prevent the user from calling **stake()** when the **unstake()** function hasn't yet been fully processed (in the example below)?

```
function stake () nonReentrant {
   ...
}

function unstake () nonReentrant {
   ...
}
```

Does it manage the `_lock` state separately for each assignment to the function, or it has the same `_lock` for all calls?

***P.S. Apologies if my question is a bit unclear, I tried my best to explain what I'd like to ask you.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It locks all functions in the same contract. In your example, both stake and unstake functions will be under the same lock

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply!